# Show/Hide TextBox when MouseHover/MouseLeave

Tags: vb.net, textbox

How can I make TEXTBOX shown or hidden based on event mousehover or mouseleave? I placed the textbox over a picture.
I just tried coding this by making property of textbox visibility to **false** but nothing happened. I think there's a code missing?

```
Private Sub TextBox1_MouseHover(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.MouseHover
        TextBox1.Visible = True
    End Sub

    Private Sub TextBox1_MouseLeave(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.MouseLeave
        TextBox1.Visible = False
    End Sub
```

Comment: Do you understand my updated answer?

Comment: Hi, Please remember to mark a relevant answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you want to show the textbox as soon as you hover of the Picture.

The `textbox` will not listen to `mouse_enter` events when it is invisible.

Use your `mouse events` on the Picture box, not the textbox.

It is worth mentioning that your `mouse leave` will fire for the picture box the moment you hover onto the now visible textbox, which will make it invisible...

```
    Dim i_Am_in_the_picture_box as Boolean 'global variable to your class

    Private Sub picbox1_MouseHover(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles picbox1.MouseHover
        TextBox1.Visible = True
    End Sub

    Private Sub picbox1_MouseLeave(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles picbox1.MouseLeave
        TextBox1.Visible = False
    End Sub
```

You may have to write some code to check when your cursor is inside the bounds of the `picturebox` when a `mouse_leave` event is triggered (Becaue entering the textbox, will trigger the `mouse_leave` event of the picturebox).

If your cursor is still inside the picturebox bounds, then do not hide the `textbox` on `picbox.mouse_leave`

**EDIT**

Further to this, based on your comment,

> thanks. but it shows the textbox wherever i mouseover. I have a
>   picture of a teeth (lower and upper teeth) and it was a PNG file. When
>   the dentist mouseover on a specific tooth the textbox will show and
>   the dentist can put the tooth's treatment history ...in short, i want
>   the textbox to be visible when mouseover in a specific area of the
>   pic. is that possible? sorry i'm just a student. i tried googling but
>   can't find any article/threads about this. :)

you will have to define custom bounds for each tooth, and then on `mouse_move`, check to see if the cursor location is inside one of those bounds. If it is, show the applicable `textbox.`

**Here is actual working code to show you how this can be done.**

1. The following example, has two "invisible" panels positioned over a picture box (Lets say over "tooth1" and "tooth2".)
2. We build two custom rectangles, using the invisible panels' location and size parameters.
3. We catch the picture box's `MouseMove` event, and check if our cursor is in one of the rectangles we created. If it is, we show a particular textbox (And we hide whatever other textbox was visible)

This can be done with less code, but the example should explain exactly how the concept works.

```
Public Class Form2

    Dim tooth1 As New Rectangle
    Dim tooth2 As New Rectangle

    Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        'use the dummy invisble panel's location and size to create our wto rectnagles on the screen
        tooth1 = New Rectangle(dummyPanel_for_tooth_1.Location, dummyPanel_for_tooth_1.Size)
        tooth2 = New Rectangle(dummyPanel_for_tooth_2.Location, dummyPanel_for_tooth_2.Size)

    End Sub

    Private Sub _set_all_other_textboxes_invisible(visibleTextboxName As String)

        If TextBox1.Name <> visibleTextboxName Then TextBox1.Visible = False
        If TextBox2.Name <> visibleTextboxName Then TextBox2.Visible = False

    End Sub

    Private Sub PictureBox1_MouseMove(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.MouseMove
        If tooth1.Contains(e.Location) Then

            'we are inside tooth 1 bounds
            TextBox1.Visible = True

            'hide the other textboxes we are not working with.
            _set_all_other_textboxes_invisible(TextBox1.Name)

            'we can exit here, no need to do any furher testing
            Exit Sub

        End If

        If tooth2.Contains(e.Location) Then

            'we are inside tooth 2 bounds
            TextBox2.Visible = True

            'hide the other textboxes we are not working with.
            _set_all_other_textboxes_invisible(TextBox2.Name)

            'we can exit here, no need to do any furher testing
            Exit Sub

        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: thanks. but it shows the textbox wherever i mouseover. 
I have a picture of a teeth (lower and upper teeth) and it was a PNG file. When the dentist mouseover on a specific tooth the textbox will show and the dentist can put the tooth's treatment history ...in short, i want the textbox to be visible when mouseover in a specific area of the pic. is that possible? 
sorry i'm just a student. i tried googling but can't find any article/threads about this. :)

Comment: Yes this is definitely possible, but you will have to define custom bounds, and check on `mousemove`, if the cursor is inside those bounds.

Comment: I think your difficulty is that you think the `mouse enter` event will fire when you hover over an invisible `textbox`. This would have solved all your problems, but unfortunately it does not work this way. When the `textbox` is invisible, it wont fire on the mouse entering it (its visually gone, for all intents and purposes).

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort! :) i really appreciate it. i'll try this :)